# SVG won't rotate on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, svg, rotation

I have an SVG circle stroke line animation, and for some reason the origin of the path is on the right, so I rotated it 270deg and it looks fine on my laptop (in Chrome AND Safari), but when I view it on my mobile (iPhone 5c), it rotates back to the right.

[Here's the **`codepen`**](http://codepen.io/mrseanbaines/pen/BQxVOX)

[image: view from iPhone 5c]

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363916/svg-transform-rotate-by-90-180-or-270-degrees-not-working-on-circle-in-safari-i

Comment: @ilokhov Thank you!